# "Terminated due to timeout" status - Hackerank

Tags: python

> Consider an array of numeric strings where each string is a positive
> number with anywhere from 1 to 10<sup>6</sup> digits. Sort the array's elements in
> non-decreasing, or ascending order of their integer values and return
> the sorted array.
>
> Example
>
> Return the array `['1', '3', '150', '200']`.

My code gets terminated due to timeout, How can I correct it?

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'bigSorting' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a STRING_ARRAY.
# The function accepts STRING_ARRAY unsorted as parameter.
#

def bigSorting(unsorted):
    unsorted = map(int,unsorted)
    unsorted =sorted(unsorted)
    unsorted = map(str, unsorted)
        
    return unsorted;

                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input().strip())

    unsorted = []

    for _ in range(n):
        unsorted_item = input()
        unsorted.append(unsorted_item)

    result = bigSorting(unsorted)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

i tried reducing code, but it still says like that
its reduced the time but still say not enough.

Comment: is it because of `unsorted_item = input()` which is exacting an input but none is given?

Comment: no, we can inout anydata

Comment: Is there something missing in "anywhere from to digits"? Shouldn't there be a range of numbers there?

Comment: It's very unclear to me how your code acquires input and what the interaction looks like. Please be more specific on how you are running the app and giving it input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to and from `int`. You can sort numeric strings by first sorting by length, then sorting strings with equal length lexicographically (as long as there are no leading zeroes).

```
def bigsorting(unsorted):
    return sorted(unsorted, key = lambda x: (len(x), x))
```